# Running RSpec example without prefix RSpec in non-Rails App fails

Tags: rspec

I have a strange behaviour in a simple Ruby project with RSpec. When I keep the generated `spec_helper.rb` as it was generated with `rspec --init`, I can run use the below syntax in my specs:

```
describe 'An ideal sandwich' do 
  it 'is delicious' do
  end
end
```

If I uncomment the section commented with `begin` and `end` in the `spec_helper.rb`, it fails with:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `describe' for main:Object
```

I should prefix all the examples with `RSpec` :

```
RSpec.describe 'An ideal sandwich' do 
  it 'is delicious' do
  end
end
```

What is the reason for that ? 
Using RSpec `3.6`, Ruby `2.4.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The most complete answer has been done by Myron Marston at RSpec discusion group that can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/rspec/sOUvFNB9Wyk/Uv4w5T5LAAAJ).